# Efficiently add column to Pandas DataFrame with values from another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, series

I have a simple database consisting of 2 tables (say, Items and Users), where a column of the Users is their **User_ID**, a column of the Items is their **Item_ID** and another column of the Items is **a foreign key to a User_ID**, for instance:

```
Items                                       Users
Item_ID  Value_A  Its_User_ID ...           User_ID  Name  ...
1        35       1                         1        Alice
2        991      1                         2        John
3        20       2
```

Imagine I want to [denormalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) this database, i.e. I'm adding the value of column Name from table Users into table Items for performance reasons when querying the data. My current solution is the following:

```
items['User_Name'] = pd.Series([users.loc[users['User_ID']==x, 'Name'].iloc[0] 
                     for x in items['Its_User_ID']])
```

That is, I'm adding the column as a Pandas Series constructed from a comprehension list, which uses **.loc[]** to retrieve the names of the users with a specific ID, and **.iloc[0]** to get the first element of the selection (which is the only one because user IDs are unique).

But this solution is really slow for large sets of items. I did the following tests:

- For 1000 items and ~200K users: 20 seconds.
- For ~400K items and ~200K users: 2.5 hours. (and this is the real data size).

Because this approach is column-wise, its execution time grows multiplicatively by the number of columns for which I'm doing this process, and gets too time-expensive. While I haven't tried using **for** loops to fill the new Series row by row, I expect that it should be much more costly. Are there other approaches that I'm ignoring? Is there a possible solution that takes a few minutes instead of a few hours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be more straightforward if you used table [merges](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

```
items.merge(users[['User_ID', 'Name']], left_on='Its_User_ID', right_on='User_ID', how='left')
```

This will add the column Name to the new dataset, which you can of-course rename later. This will be much more efficient that doing the operation via a for loop column-wise.

Answer (score 1):

Use the high performance database operations provided by Panda, see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging).

For example:

```
pd.merge(items, users, left_on='Its_User_ID', right_on='User_ID')
```

Comment: Duplicate answer?